# How to apply upload limit for google storage bucket per day/month/etc

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Is there a way how to apply upload limit for google storage bucket per day/month/year?

Is there is a way how to apply limit on amount of Network traffic?
Is there is a way how to apply limit on Class A operations?
Is there is a way how to apply limit on Class B operations?

I found only Queries per 100 seconds per user and Queries per day using
https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota instructions, but this is JSON Api quotas
(I even not sure what kind of api is used inside of StorageClient c# client class)

Answer (score 1):

For defining Quotas, and by the way SLO, you need to have SLI: Service level indicator. that means to have metrics on what you want to observe.

Here, it's not the case. Cloud Storage haven't indicator on the volume of data per day. Thus, you don't have built in indicator and metrics, ... and quotas.

If you want it, you have to build something by your own. To wrap all the Cloud Storage call in a service that count the volume of blob per days and then you will be able to apply your own rules on this personal indicator.

Of course, for preventing any by pass, you have to deny direct access to the buckets and only grant your "indicator service" to access them. Same things for the bucket creation, to register the new buckets in your service.

Not an easy task...